# I want to delete few SQLite tables(NOT DROP) and get an acknowledgement

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to delete few SQLite tables(NOT DROP) and get an acknowledgement. How can i write a function in db handler??

```
 public void DeleteUserData(int userID) 
 {
    String[] queries =new String[6];
    queries[0]="delete from COMMONS where USERID="+userID;
    queries[1]="delete from POINT where USERID="+userID;
    queries[2]="delete from USER where USERID="+userID;
    queries[3]="delete from OFFICE"; 
    for(int i=0;i<queries.length;i++) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(queries[i]);
    } 
 }
```

I tried this, is there any better way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I remember correctly, db handler has an option to execute native SQL queries. All you have to do is execute "delete tableName" and it will delete all of the records in the table with the name tableName.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
int returnRows = db.delete("table_name", null, null);
```

Comment: If returnRows count is more than -1 that means all rows in your table have been deleted.

Comment: As per documentation, the number of rows affected if a whereClause is passed in, 0 otherwise. To remove all rows and get a count pass "1" as the whereClause.